# Lock row in grid in extjs

Tags: extjs

How to lock a specific row in extjs.

Comment: He means that he wants a row in the grid to stay in the same position when scrolling the data up or down.  Think of a total row that you always want to see, but you want the rest of the data to be scrollable.

Answer (score -1):

One way is to handle the click event (or other appropriate event), determine the row selected, and return immediately if the row is "locked."

The RowSelectionModel also fires the rowSelected event; as others have pointed out in this forum, this event is fired for either a keyboard row selection or a mouse row selection.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this,

```
grid.getSelectionModel().lock();
```